# 'The query contains references to items defined on a different data context' altough dbcontext is the same

Tags: c#, linq, dbcontext

```
public IQueryable<SMMSALESUNIT> GetPersonalSalesUnitQuery()
{
    var q = from r in dax.SMMSALESUNITs
        where r.DATAAREAID == COMPANYID
        && r.ACTIVE == 1
        select r;
}
public IQueryable<SMMSALESUNITMEMBER> GetPersonalSalesUnitMemberQuery()
{
    IQueryable<SMMSALESUNIT> salesUnit = new SMMSALESUNIT().GetPersonalSalesUnitQuery();
    var q = from r in dax.SMMSALESUNITMEMBERs
            join s in salesUnit on r.SALESUNITID equals s.SALESUNITID
            select r;
    return q;
}
```

On `q.ToList()` the following error occurs:
"The query contains references to items defined on a different data context"

Comment: Show the declaration and initialization of `dax`.

Comment: .. and show how (on what instance) you are calling these two methods

Comment: The last time I saw this, it was because of a class-scoped variable was being used by two different threads.  One thread with one context set it while the other thread was in the middle of using it.  If this class is being used by multiple threads, get rid of all the class-scoped variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is (most likely) here:

```
IQueryable<SMMSALESUNIT> salesUnit = new SMMSALESUNIT().GetPersonalSalesUnitQuery();
```

`dax` used in `GetPersonalSalesUnitQuery` seems to be instance member of class `SMMSALESUNIT`. Here you create new `SMALLSALESUNIT` and so new instance of `dax`. Then you do

```
var q = from r in dax.SMMSALESUNITMEMBERs
        join s in salesUnit on r.SALESUNITID equals s.SALESUNITID
        select r;
```

This is another `dax`, not the instance member of `SMALLSALESUNIT` you created above. So you try to join queries from two different contexts, which fails.

Comment: Agreed. He should remove "new SMMSALESUNIT()." from the line you mentioned and problem solved.